# Function that is not Space Constructible

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

I'm reading Sipser's *Introduction to the Theory of Computation*, and I'm reading about space-constructible functions. He gives the following definition:

> A function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is *space constructible* if the function that maps the string $1^n$ to the binary representation of $f(n)$ is computable in space $O(f(n))$.

He follows up by saying,

> All commonly occurring functions that are at least $O(\log n)$ are space constructible, including the functions $\log_2 n$, $n \log_2 n$, and $n^2$.

My question:  What is an example of a function that is $\Omega(\log n)$ that is *not* space constructible?

Comment: "at least $O(\log n)$" -- this is such an empty statement that I am sad to see it used in a widely adopted textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually such examples are specifically "tailored", using hard problems.
Perhaps the easiest way is to take the halting problem:
$$HALT=\{\langle M\rangle: M\text{ is a TM that halts on }\epsilon\}$$
and consider the encodings of TMs as numbers, in such a way that no two numbers are encoded to the same TM (e.g. by leading 0s). This can be achieved using unary encoding, for example.

Now, consider the function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ defined as follows:
$f(n)=2n$ if $n$ represents a TM in HALT, and $f(n)=2n+1$ otherwise.

This function is $\theta(n)$, but clearly it is not space constructible, since constructing it would enable you to solve the halting problem.

A similar example can be constructed from a problem which is harder than PSPACE (e.g. a problem complete in EXPSPACE).

However, these example are somewhat "ugly". A more elegant example is the [busy beaver function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver), which is non-computable simply because it "grows too fast".

Comment: Your example with the halting problem really helped clarify this for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most functions are not space constructible. For example, let $A$ be a non-computable set, and define
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases} 2n & \text{if } n \in A, \\ 2n+1 & \text{if } n \notin A. \end{cases}
$$
This is a monotone increasing function which is $\Theta(n)$ but isn't space constructible.

Here is a more interesting example. Instead of taking $A$ to be non-computable, take a language which is in $\mathrm{SPACE}(n^2) \setminus \mathrm{SPACE}(n)$. Such a language exists by the space hierarchy theorem. Again $f(n)$ is a monotone $\Theta(n)$ function, which is computable in space $O(n^2)$ but not in space $O(n)$.